# Upgrade pip to ver18 on anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

I am using anaconda 64-bit for python v3.6 on Windows 10.

Whenever I use pip on anaconda, I get the following message;

```
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I read that the safe way to upgrade pip on anaconda is to use conda;

```
conda update pip
```

However, using the conda command does not upgrade to ver18. Is it safe to use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` to force pip to be upgraded to ver18? Any risk of breaking anaconda? Anyone tried?

Comment: Have you enabled Conda-forge?

Comment: Also, 64-bit on which platform? According to the Conda-forge repo. [`pip`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pip) 18.0 is available on x86_64 Linux, Windows, and macOS, but it may not be available on, say, PPC64 Linux or ARM64 Linux or x86_64 FreeBSD.

Comment: I tried to replicate the problem on conda 4.3.30 (python 3.6 macOS) but was unable to.  If merely disabling the pip upgrade messaging satisfies your needs, you can do so by leveraging the `--disable-pip-version-check` option.

Comment: I am using Windows 10. Updated the question details.

Comment: @abarnert, thanks about the tip on COnda-forge. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I will answer my own question. I got the answer thanks to one of the comments from abarnert who suggested conda-forge.

Run the commands below;

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge 
conda update pip
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure should be able to not only write your own answer, but also accept it. If so, you should, for the benefit of future searchers with the same problem, and so people can link future duplicate questions here, and I think you even get some rep points.

Comment: I'm on windows 10 and conda update pip did not work, even though conda-forge is at the top of my channel list.

Answer (score 3):

A bit different here but I'm using Linux.

Even though I had `conda-forge` in my channel list, I still couldn't just run `conda update pip` to update. I had to run the following to install that specific version.

`conda install pip=18.0`

Comment: Trying conda install pip=18.0 downgrades python from 3.7 to 3.6, on a windows 10 pc with Anaconda python 5.3 (64-bit) installed.

Comment: Even using the `conda-forge` channel?

Answer (score 3):

Enter the following command:

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: On macos 10.13.6 with anaconda 4.5.1, the accepted answer above ran without error, but did not change my pip version.  But running the code in this answer (after removing '.exe'), did upgrade my pip to 18.1. Yeah!

Answer (score 1):

Small update:

Anaconda has recently distributed `pip` 18.1 version.

Both via Anaconda Prompt or via Anaconda Navigator, you should be able to upgrade `pip` and its dependencies (`libcur`, `pycurl`, `qt`, so on and so forth).

Answer (score 1):

Simple `pip upgrade` command worked for me

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Let me know if that doesn't work for you.